# Issue with For Loop to paste special a row across worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I am trying to copy the last row and paste special at the next row. When I try the following code  for an individual worksheet it works fine:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim LR  As Long
    LR = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Rows(LR).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows(LR + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

But when I am trying to loop through all worksheets, it is only pasting special in one of the worksheets the same copied row number of times instead of repeating to each worksheet. Could you please advise what I am doing wrong on the following for loop?

```
 Sub Macro1()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim LR  As Long
 Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

 For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

    If ws3.Name Like "*.plt" Then

    LR = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Rows(LR).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows(LR + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

   End If
   Next ws

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save some overhead, you should first refrain from using `.Select` and `.Selection.*`. If you anyways want to copy just the value you should do so via the `.Value` property of the cell. Secondly, you should use the `With` statement to make sure that you are referencing the target sheet. Finally, you should set unused objects to `Nothing` in the end. The following code should do the trick.

**Code**

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        With ws
            If .Name Like "*.plt" Then
                Set rng = .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow
                rng.Offset(1).Value = rng.Value
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: this is brilliant! works great and many thanks for explaing this in details!

Answer (score 0):

I think that this

```
If ws3.Name Like "*.plt" Then
```

might be your issue. You need to enable Option Explicit so that you do not use undefined names.

Also, make

```
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
```

to

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have tried this but still something is wrokg, but the other answer from 'THOTHAL' working great and I have also learned a new method. but really thanks for trying to help me :)